# C++: How to overload pow for user type?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a user-built type `T` for which I would like to give meaning to the notion of a power `pow(T1, T2)`.

Then, in templated code, I would like to be able to write `std::pow(a, b)`, and then if `a, b` happen to be doubles or floats, it does what it always does, and if they happen to be of type `T`, then I want to call my overload.

How do I do this?

I could give my type a `pow`-operator, but how do I then differentiate between `std::pow` and `pow`-operator?

Comment: If your `pow` function is in the global namespace, you can disambiguate it as `::pow(T1, T2)`. Otherwise if the operator is defined, say inside the `T1` class, it would be `T1::pow(T1, T2);`

Answer (score 6):

You are not allowed to overloaded function into the `std` namespace.  A typical solution for this is to declare your function in the same namespace as the custom type like

```
namespace my_code
{
    struct foo {};

    foo pow(foo base, int power)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

And then in your function where you are using `pow` on thing you would add `using std::pow`.  This lets you then write your code like

```
void bar()
{
    using std::pow;
    //...
    auto a = pow(10,3);
    //...
    auto b = pow(foo{}, 3);

}
```

and the line `pow(10,3)` will pick the `std` version of the function while `pow(foo, 3)` will find your overload through [argument dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: Doesn't have to be in the global namespace though, just the same namespace as `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to add names to `std` namespaces. The only thing which you can do is to add specializations. If you are willing to ignore that (many people do!) the simplest solution would be to add this overload into namespace `std`.

A fully conformant solution would be to add the overload to the one of the visible namespaces, and than whenever you are planning on calling one of the available `pow` versions, do this:

```
using std::pow;

pow(a, b);
```

Than, if a and b happen to be of types supported by `std::pow`, it will be called, otherwise, your overload will.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly overload `std::pow`.  The standard forbids adding new overloads to functions in the `std` namespace.

What you can do, is use ADL to select the `pow` function you want similar to the way people often add `swap` overloads:

```
namespace my_namespace {

struct my_type {
    explicit my_type(double d) : my_num{d} {}
    double my_num;
};

my_type pow(const my_type& a, const my_type& b) {
    std::cout << "my_namespace::pow(my_type, my_type) called\n";
    return my_type{std::pow(a.my_num, b.my_num)};
}

}

template <typename T>
void foo() {
    using std::pow;
    pow(T{2}, T{10});
}

int main() {
    foo<float>(); // calls std::pow
    foo<my_namespace::my_type>(); // calls my_namespace::pow
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36c10aeb224ede1a)